# once all divs have been clicked how do you change the CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the background color for all the divs **once** they have been clicked. This code allows the change to happen but I can click on the same div 3 times and get the same output. Anyone know a good solution to this? Thank you!

```js
        var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes')
        var box1 = document.querySelector('#box1')
        var box2 = document.querySelector('#box2')
        var box3 = document.querySelector('#box3')
        var clickCounter = 0
        
        function handleColor (box){
            box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            clickCounter = clickCounter + 1
            console.log(clickCounter);
            if (clickCounter > 2) {
                reset()
            }
        }
        
        for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            boxes[i].addEventListener("click", () => handleColor(boxes[i]));
               
        }
        
        function reset() {
            box1.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
            box2.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
            box3.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
        }
```

```css
.boxes {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="boxes" id="box1"></div>
    <div class="boxes" id="box2"></div>
    <div class="boxes" id="box3"></div>
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: "change the background color for all the divs once they have been clicked" could mean changing _all_ divs once _any_ is clicked, or _only after all_ are clicked _once_ - or anything in-between. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to flag each respective box and in order to control if it has been clicked at least once.

In this case you can use the class `.clicked` both as a flag in order to control whether you should reset or not, but for styling as well

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes');
var box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');
var box2 = document.querySelector('#box2');
var box3 = document.querySelector('#box3');

function handleColor (box){
    box.classList.add('clicked');

    if (box1.classList.contains("clicked") && box2.classList.contains("clicked") && box3.classList.contains("clicked")) {
        reset();
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].addEventListener("click", () => handleColor(boxes[i]));    
}

function reset() {
    box1.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    box2.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    box3.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

    for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].classList.remove('clicked');    
    }
}
```

```
.boxes {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.boxes.clicked {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember for each box whether it has been clicked or not and then on clicking a box go through all the others to see if they have all been clicked.

There are several ways of remembering: using a CSS class, within JS or within the HTML.

This snippet remembers by adding an attribute 'hasBeenClicked' with value 1 to a box element when it is clicked.

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes')
var box1 = document.querySelector('#box1')
var box2 = document.querySelector('#box2')
var box3 = document.querySelector('#box3')

function handleColor(box) {
  box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  box.setAttribute('hasBeenClicked', 1);
  let clickCounter = 0;
  boxes.forEach(box => {
    clickCounter += (box.getAttribute('hasBeenClicked') == 1) ? 1 : 0;
  });
  if (clickCounter == boxes.length) {
    reset()
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener("click", () => handleColor(boxes[i]));

}

function reset() {
  box1.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
  box2.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
  box3.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
}
```

```css
.boxes {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes" id="box1"></div>
<div class="boxes" id="box2"></div>
<div class="boxes" id="box3"></div>
```